# Getting error while checking the Angular-cli version

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

We are trying to setup angular-cli in a windows 10 machine. After doing all the installation, we are getting the following error.

```
Node.js version v11.7.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

v11.7.0 is between the minimum node.js versions. But still, the error is coming. Can you guys help me to resolve?

```
node -version : 11.7
npm -version : 6.4.1
ng -version : getting the above mentioned error.
```

Comment: find a solution yet? have the same problem